# Understanding a Cosine Derivative

Tags: trigonometry, derivatives

Let $c$ be a constant. Why is it that

> $$
> D_x \left(- \frac{\cos(cx)}{c} \right) = \sin(cx)?
> $$

I understand that $D_x \cos(x) = - \sin(x)$.  So what trigonometric identity is allowing us to infer the above?

Comment: The chain rule. $\qquad$

Comment: Often I post something just because I think a question can be answered more simply than it is in the other answers.  See my answer below. $\qquad$

Answer (score 19, accepted):

You are just using the chain rule. Hence you get by using $D_x\cos(x) = -\sin(x)$ and $D_x(cx) = c$ that
$$
D_x \left(- \frac{\cos(cx)}{c} \right) = - c \frac{-\sin(cx)}{c} = \sin(cx)
$$
I hope that helps you :)

Answer (score 17):

$$f(x) = {-\cos (cx) \over c}$$ 
$$\begin{align}  f^\prime(x) & = \lim_{h \to 0} {{{-\cos (c(x + h)) \over c} - {-\cos (cx) \over c}}\over h}\\
& = \lim_{h \to 0} {\cos (cx)-\cos (c(x + h)) \over hc}\\
& = \lim_{h \to 0} {-2 \sin ({cx + cx + ch \over 2})\times\sin ({cx - cx - ch \over 2}) \over hc}\\
& = \lim_{h \to 0} {2 \sin (cx + {ch \over 2})\times \sin ({ch \over 2}) \over hc}\\
& = \lim_{h \to 0} {\sin (cx + {ch \over 2})\times\sin ({ch \over 2}) \over {hc \over 2}}\\
& = \sin (cx)\times\lim_{h \to 0} {\sin ({ch \over 2}) \over {hc \over 2}}\\
& = \sin (cx)
 \end{align}$$

If you don't like chain rule :)

Answer (score 7):

By De Moivre,

$$\cos(nx)+i\sin(nx)=(\cos(x)+i\sin(x))^n.$$

Then by the derivative of a power,

$$(\cos(nx)+i\sin(nx))'\\
=\left((\cos(x)+i\sin(x))^n\right)'\\
=n(\cos(x)+i\sin(x))^{n-1}\left(\cos(x)+i\sin(x)\right)'\\
=n\left((\cos((n-1)x)+i\sin((n-1)x))^{n-1}\right)\left(-\sin(x)+i\cos(x)\right)\\
=n\left((-\cos((n-1)x)\sin(x)-\sin((n-1)x)\cos(x)\\
-i\sin((n-1)x)\sin(x)+)^{n-1}+i\cos((n-1)x)\cos(x)+)^{n-1}\right)\\
=n(-\sin(nx)+i\cos(nx)),$$
which establishes the claim for all integer $n$.

But all of this is a stupid sledgehammer compared to the simple use of the chain rule.

Comment: Lmao, I love the overkill.

Answer (score 4):

Let,$f\left( x \right) =\cos { x } ,g\left( x \right) =cx\quad $ then composition of $f$ and $g$ will be $f\circ g=f\left( g\left( x \right)  \right) \quad =\cos { \left( cx \right)  } $
we know from the chain rule that $$\\ f^{ \prime  }\left( g\left( x \right)  \right) =f^{ \prime  }\left( g\left( x \right)  \right) \quad g^{ \prime  }\left( x \right) $$ and consider the $D_{ x }\left( f\left( x \right)  \right) =-\sin { \left( cx \right)  } \\ { D }_{ x }\left( g\left( x \right)  \right) =c$

we get $$D_{ x }\left( -\frac { \cos  (cx) }{ c }  \right) =-\frac { 1 }{ c } { D }_{ x }\left( \cos { \left( cx \right)  }  \right) =-\frac { 1 }{ c } \cdot \left( -\sin { \left( cx \right)  }  \right) \cdot c=\sin { \left( cx \right)  } \\ $$

Answer (score 4):

\begin{align}
y & = \cos(cx) \\[10pt]
y & = \cos u & u & = cx \\[10pt]
\frac{dy}{du} & = -\sin u & \frac{du}{dx} & = c
\end{align}

Now apply the **chain rule:**
$$
\frac{dy}{dx} = \frac{dy}{du} \cdot \frac{du}{dx} = \Big(-\sin u\Big) \cdot c = \Big(-\sin(cx)\Big) \cdot c.
$$

Comment: Possibly the lack of words?

Comment: @Daniel, Sometimes "words get in the way", as Miss Estefan has once said. ;)

Comment: And yet here it is being downvoted.

Comment: @DanielR.Collins : In some places in m.s.e. there is indeed insufficient use of words, and in some places there are far too many words, and often both problems occur in the same paragraph.  However, I have now added some words. $\qquad$

Comment: Divide the last equation by $c$ in order to get it in the same form as _OP_. I think this is why it didn't get voted much.

Comment: Although i upvoted the answer, i don't get how this isn't a duplicate of the accepted answer. There are already 2 duplicates of the accepted answer. Anyway thanks for $\quad$.

Answer (score 1):

The easiest and most elegant way is to apply the chain rule literally:
$\def\lfrac#1#2{{\large\frac{#1}{#2}}}$

> $\lfrac{d(\cos(cx))}{dx} \overset{\text{chain rule}}= \lfrac{d(\cos(cx))}{d(cx)} \times \lfrac{d(cx)}{dx} = -\sin(cx) \times c$ for any variable $x$ and constant $c$.

Of course this then gives $\lfrac{d(-\frac1c\cos(cx))}{dx} = -\lfrac1c ( -\sin(cx) \times c ) = \sin(cx)$.